# radeon 0000:02:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10492msec

Tags: drivers, radeon, gpu, lockup

I have recently (last 4 weeks) been encountering an intermittent graphics lockup, associated with messages like:

radeon 0000:02:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10492msec
Dec  8 15:26:30 tinonee kernel: [   87.799459] radeon 0000:02:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x00000000000000b3 last fence id 0x00000000000000b4 on ring 0)
...

MSI X58 Pro, Intel i7
RV730 PRO [Radeon HD 4650]
Currently running 16.04.1 LTS
core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch

Screen blacks out then returns every 20 s or so, mouse still moves cursor and audio persists, but no response from keyboard and mouse buttons. Initially I can ssh from another machine, but even this freezes up after 20-30 s.

I can see reports on LKML of similar problems with the driver from 2012-2013, which can be precipitated by certain web pages (I associate the problem with OWA over Firefox). So I am *guessing* it is not a hardware fault.

Do I need to add in abstruse driver directives, or will the defaults be fixed shortly?

Comment: My Ubuntu 18.04 Hp desktop hangs with a similar error when it comes out of sleep/standby mode. The repeating error includes the words: "...radeon...ring...stalled for more than...sec..." The error comes and goes with multiple 18.04 installs.