# System Lockup: radeon ring stalled for more than 10280msec

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, radeon

My system is frequently, but intermittently locking up.  I am unsure of what to do next to troubleshoot and/or whether I should report this as a bug.  Advice would be appreciated.  Note that my question is similar to one previously posted at [radeon 0000:02:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10492msec](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858301/radeon-00000200-0-ring-0-stalled-for-more-than-10492msec) that has yet to be responded to.

My system intermittently locks up every few days.  When that happens, the screen goes to black, then returns.  At that point, the time on the clock indicates that the screen is frozen, but audio continues to play for 30 seconds to a minute.  The keyboard and mouse do not affect what's being displayed, but I can  Alt - SysRq - REISUB to restart.

Every time (6 crashes and counting), /var/log/kern.log indicates that

```
kernel: [353692.378886] radeon 0000:03:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10280msec
kernel: [353692.378896] radeon 0000:03:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x00000000006e96e5 last fence id 0x00000000006e96e9 on ring 0)
```

just before the system locks.  Different ring numbers are reported as stalling at different times.

I'm running 16.04 LTS.  I have a Radeon HD graphics card.

```
:~$ lspci | grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]

:~$ lspci -v -s 03:00.0
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at d3d20000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
I/O ports at 7000 [size=256]
Expansion ROM at d3d00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: radeon
Kernel modules: radeon
```

In looking for solutions, I found an old bug report from 14.04 that is currently unassigned https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1409393.

[Edit:]  Based on @MichaelBay 's suggestion, I ran the Checkbox graphics card tests and everything passed.  I also I ran MemoryTest.  No errors were found after 3 passes.  Finally, I loaded Psensor to check the GPU temperatures, but there are no GPU readings.

Comment: Also, Based on information at 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD 
and 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver
I believe I am using the correct driver.

Comment: Could be hardware. The driver is correct as in the only one you can use now.

Comment: @MichaelBay - thanks for your suggestion.  I ran a few hardware tests (see the edits in the original post), but if you have other suggestions about how I can test the hardware, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I get `radeon 0000:04:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10240msec` on my **[AMD/ATI] RV620 GL [FirePro 2450]** when I run the Opera web browser under **Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS** for a few minutes.  No problems ever with Firefox or any other program, only Opera.

```
[128524.943553] radeon 0000:04:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10240msec
[128524.943565] radeon 0000:04:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x000000000029caf6 last fence id 0x000000000029cafc on ring 0)
[128524.955392] radeon 0000:04:00.0: Saved 185 dwords of commands on ring 0.
[128524.955409] radeon 0000:04:00.0: GPU softreset: 0x00000009
[128524.955413] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_008010_GRBM_STATUS      = 0xA2303030
[128524.955417] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_008014_GRBM_STATUS2     = 0x00000003
[128524.955420] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_000E50_SRBM_STATUS      = 0x200010C0
[128524.955423] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_008674_CP_STALLED_STAT1 = 0x00000000
[128524.955426] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_008678_CP_STALLED_STAT2 = 0x00008002
[128524.955429] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_00867C_CP_BUSY_STAT     = 0x00008086
[128524.955432] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_008680_CP_STAT          = 0x80018645
[128524.955435] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_00D034_DMA_STATUS_REG   = 0x44C83D57
[128525.013038] radeon 0000:04:00.0: R_008020_GRBM_SOFT_RESET=0x00007FEF
[128525.013097] radeon 0000:04:00.0: SRBM_SOFT_RESET=0x00000100
[128525.015187] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_008010_GRBM_STATUS      = 0xA0003030
[128525.015191] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_008014_GRBM_STATUS2     = 0x00000003
[128525.015195] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_000E50_SRBM_STATUS      = 0x200080C0
[128525.015198] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_008674_CP_STALLED_STAT1 = 0x00000000
[128525.015201] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_008678_CP_STALLED_STAT2 = 0x00000000
[128525.015204] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_00867C_CP_BUSY_STAT     = 0x00000000
[128525.015207] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_008680_CP_STAT          = 0x80100000
[128525.015210] radeon 0000:04:00.0:   R_00D034_DMA_STATUS_REG   = 0x44C83D57
[128525.015220] radeon 0000:04:00.0: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
[128525.031584] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
[128525.034184] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x0000000000142000).
[128525.034222] radeon 0000:04:00.0: WB enabled
[128525.034224] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000010000c00
[128525.034579] radeon 0000:04:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x00000000000521d0
[128525.034797] debugfs: File 'radeon_ring_gfx' in directory '0' already present!
[128525.066237] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[128525.066242] debugfs: File 'radeon_ring_uvd' in directory '0' already present!
[128525.240884] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[128525.240893] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[128535.695467] radeon 0000:04:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10456msec
[128535.695479] radeon 0000:04:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x000000000029caf8 last fence id 0x000000000029cafc on ring 0)
[128535.697433] [drm:r600_ib_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: fence wait failed (-35).
[128535.697551] [drm:radeon_ib_ring_tests [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: failed testing IB on GFX ring (-35).
```